# How to make System partition in Oracle 11g?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I am very new to database .I would like to do system partition for a existing large database  table in oracle. Can someone suggest 
How i can achieve system partition for existing table in oracle database ?

Note i am only looking for System Partition not looking for range or Hash or composite Partition.

Comment: What is a "system partition"?

Comment: That's an Oracle Database method of data partitioning where the application logic controls the partition structure.

Comment: See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm#BABFCBHC) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#BABJBDCC) ... but not sure that really helps explain what the OP wants to do here.

Comment: OP means ?  Need an example for reference to do system Partition for my existing table .

Comment: @AnuragKumar - [original poster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79804/whats-stackexchange-ese-for-op) - i.e. you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, an existing table cannot be partitioned. You will have to recreate it.
There is an Oracle package called `dbms_redefinition` for just this scenario (see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_redefi.htm for details), but I will provide a very simple example without using this package.

Imagine you have the following non-partitioned table:

```
create table T_TABLE
(
  pkey         NUMBER not null,
  t_data       VARCHAR2(250) not null,
  partitionkey NUMBER not null
);
```

If you want to partition that table, the first step would be to rename the table:

```
alter table t_table rename to old_table;
```

Then, create the new table

```
create table T_TABLE
(
  pkey         NUMBER not null,
  t_data       VARCHAR2(250) not null,
  partitionkey NUMBER not null
)
partition by system
(
   partition p1 tablespace users,
   partition p2 tablespace users,
   partition p3 tablespace users
);
```

Now you can insert your table rows from the old table into the new table. Your application/sql needs to tell the server in which partition to insert.
For example, like this:

```
insert into t_table partition (p1) select * from old_table where partitionkey = 1;    
insert into t_table partition (p2) select * from old_table where partitionkey = 2;
insert into t_table partition (p3) select * from old_table where partitionkey = 3;        
commit;
```

Now you can drop your old table.

```
drop table old_table;
```

Comment: Fyi, Oracle have [introduced partitioning non-partitioned tables in 12.2.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/exadata-express-cloud/csdbf/oracle-database-12-2-new-features.html#GUID-D5D9C311-3597-4494-B8DE-CE33EE4FA546)

Comment: Cool - thanks for that hint. Though it will probably take years until I can use that new feature.

Comment: Yeah, I'm in the same boat (I'd loooooove to get my hands on the 12.2 extended to_char/to_number/etc functions!), but I thought it was info worth sharing *{:-) I'd credit the blog where I read about it, except I can't remember who posted about it now!

Comment: @ThomasTschernich thanks a lot  for providing this solution :-)

Comment: @AnuragKumar If you liked this answer, please consider accepting it (click the green button to the left of my answer).